# "Geschlossen" oder "abgeschlossen"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ich hatte den Eindruck, ich verstünde den Unterschied zwischen *geschlossen* und  *abgeschlossen* : abgeschlossen ist "mehr" als geschlossen (um es ein bisschen vage auszudrücken).
Aber diese "Regel" scheint nicht immer zuzutreffen: in der Mathematik spricht man von *abgeschlossene Menge*, aber von *geschlossene Differentialform*.
Ist im Allgemeinen der Unterschied streng aufrechtzuerhalten ? Gibt es eine Faustregel um sich nicht zu irren?

Comment: Suchst du jetzt eine allgemeingültige Unterscheidung der Begriffe geschlossen und abgeschlossen, oder speziell auf die Anwendungsfälle in der Mathematik? Falls allgemein: "geschlossen" heißt "nicht offen", "abgeschlossen" heißt "verriegelt", "blockiert". Fall Mathematik: Dann frag auf http://math.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: Lieber @Em1, math.stackexchange [ist mir nicht völlig unbekannt](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg), aber ich bin nicht sicher ob die Frage da wirklich reinpasst. Wie dem auch sei, ich bin an eine allgemeine Unterscheidung interessiert  und  danke dir für deine Erklärung .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die von Dir angesprochene Steigerung von "geschlossen" zu "abgeschlossen" funktioniert zwar in manchen Kontexten:

> Die Tür ist abgeschlossen: sie ist geschlossen und zusätzlich mit einem Schloß o.ä. zugesperrt.

aber sowohl [geschlossen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geschlossen_abgeriegelt_komplett) als auch [abgeschlossen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abgeschlossen) haben noch weitere, eigene Bedeutungen, die über diese "mechanische" Sicht hinausgehen.

Insbesondere kann "abgeschlossen" bedeuten "abgesondert / isoliert" und "fertig in sich vollendet". Beides trifft auf eine abgeschlossene Menge zu.

Sie ist isoliert: für jeden Punkt außerhalb der Menge findest Du immer noch einen Punkt, der "näher dran" ist, aber auch nicht zu der Menge gehört. Es gibt keinen Punkt mit "direktem Kontakt".

Sie ist "in sich vollendet": man kann zu einer beliebigen Menge deren "Abschluß" bilden - die kleinste abgeschlossene Obermenge. Dazu betrachtet man alle konvergenten Folgen von Elementen der Menge und fügt deren Grenzwerte zu der Menge hinzu - solange, bis es nichts mehr hinzuzufügen gibt.

Mit Differentialformen kenne ich mich nicht aus; da kann ich nur vermuten, daß es keine Grundlage für die Verwendung von "abgeschlossen" gibt, bzw. daß der Begriff "geschlossen" hier etwas anderes betonen soll.

Comment: Grossartige Antwort, Matthias. Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 7):

In Ergänzung zu den bisherigen Antworten, kann man noch ein weiteres Beispiel aus der Physik heranziehen: die Thermodynamik. Auch dort spricht man von offenen, geschlossenen und abgeschlossenen Systemen.

Geschlossene Systeme tauschen mit ihrer Umgebung keine Masse (Materie) aus. Es kann ihnen aber Energie und Arbeit zu- oder abgeführt werden.

Abgeschlossene Systeme (bzw. isolierte Systeme, in diesem Zusammenhang) tauschen weder Materie noch Energie aus.

Auch hier ist also "abgeschlossen" eine härtere Bedingung als "geschlossen".

Answer (score 5):

Ich fürchte, eine einfache Regel gibt es nicht. Manche der Bedeutungen überlappen sich, und in manchen Situationen können beide Begriffe synonym verwendet werden:

Bedeutungen für *geschlossen* als Partizip II von [schließen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schlieszen):

- nicht offen, zu:

  > Die Tür ist geschlossen.

  das heißt sie man kann nicht hindurchgehen ohne sie zu öffnen, aber sie ist nicht notwendigerweise versperrt. Wenn jemand etwas schließt, so ist es nach diesem Zeitpunkt geschlossen.

Bedeutungen von [geschlossen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geschlossen_abgeriegelt_komplett) als Adjektiv:

- gemeinsam,
- einheitlich
- zusammenhängend

> Eine geschlossene Linie.
>   Eine geschlossene Gruppe.
>   Eine geschlossene Wolkendecke.
>   
>   Bedeutungen von *abgeschlossen* als Partizip II von [abschließen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abschlieszen):

- versperrt, zugesperrt

  > Die Tür ist abgeschlossen.
- abgesondert, getrennt
- beendet

  > Der Fall ist abgeschlossen.

Bedeutungen von [abgeschlossen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abgeschlossen) als Adjektiv:

- abgesondert, getrennt
- in sich geschlossen
- vollendet

Ich bin mit der historischen Entstehungsgeschichte der in der Frage erwähnten mathematischen Begriffe nicht vertraut, aber die Bedeutungen, die der Duden für die adjektivische Verwendung von *abgeschlossen* anführt, scheinen mir für *abgeschlossene Mengen* sehr passend.

*Geschlossen* bedeuted in der Mathematik meist *zusammenhängend*, ohne Lücken:

> geschlossen Kurve
>   geschlossene Lösung

und die *geschlossene Form* einer Gleichung besteht, soweit ich mich erinnere, aus einer endlichen Anzahl von Termen, die das Problem vollständig beschreiben.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn man "abgeschlossen" sagt, dann drückt man eine gewisse Distanz zum Objekt oder zur Tätigkeit aus.

"Geschlossen" hingegen sagt, dass es nicht frei zugänglich ist.

Somit ist der Unterschied eine kleine Steigerung zwischen geschlossen und abgeschlossen

Beispiel:

"Wir haben *geschlossen*"

"Die Tür ist **abgeschlossen**, damit kein Einbrecher hereinkommt"

Comment: "drückt man eine gewisse Distanz zum Objekt oder zur Tätigkeit aus" - Inwiefern denn das?? *"Ich habe (soeben) Projekt XY abgeschlossen."*.... Distanz? keine..